# Is there a Python equivalent to C#'s DateTime.TryParse()?

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, exception, tryparse

Is there an equivalent to C#'s `DateTime.TryParse()` in Python?

I'm referring to the fact that it avoids throwing an exception, not the fact that it guesses the format.

Comment: General note: You won't find many `try_parse_*` methods in Python. The idiom usually is "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission", i.e. just do it and catch exceptions (if you can handle them).

Comment: @delnan:  C#'s `DateTime.TryParse` guesses at the time format of a string.  It's not a case of "look before you leap."

Comment: @Steven: `if (!DateTime.TryParse(input, date)) { /* error message */ }` *is* LBYL. The EAFP version if `try { date = DateTime.Parse(input); } except (SomeException) { /* error message */ }`. Unless you're trying to tell me `TryParse` methods generally do `try { ...; return true; } except (...) { return false; } `.

Comment: @delnan:  At issue in this question is to find a method in Python that guesses at the date format of a string.  EAFP vs LBYL is orthagonal to this question.  The word "try" in the method name is not referring to EAFP or LBYL.

Comment: @Steven: I was actually referring to the fact that it doesn't throw an exception, not the fact that it guesses the date format... I'll clarify that

Comment: Well, looks like I was totally wrong.  Answer deleted.

Comment: This question title is unintelligible to 99.9% of Python programmers, I strongly want to edit it to: **"How to try...catch multiple datetime formats and suppress/handle the exceptions for all those that mismatch?"**. Strip it of the C# jargon.

Comment: Related question: [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime). Probably that should be the canonical question.

Comment: PeterMortensen: in response to your latest edit, you can make any Python function throw an exception simply by checking if its output is correct, then raising whichever Exception if not.

Answer (score 29):

If you don't want the exception, catch the exception.

```
try:
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
except ValueError:
    d = None
```

In the zen of Python, explicit is better than implicit. `strptime` ***always*** returns a datetime parsed in the exact format specified. This makes sense, because you have to define the behavior in case of failure, maybe what you really want is.

```
except ValueError:
    d = datetime.datetime.now()
```

or

```
except ValueError:
    d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
```

or

```
except ValueError:
    raise WebFramework.ServerError(404, "Invalid date")
```

By making it explicit, it's clear to the next person who reads it what the failover behavior is, and that it is what you need it to be.

---

Or maybe you're confident that the date cannot be invalid; it's coming from a database DATETIME, column, in which case there won't be an exception to catch, and so don't catch it.

Comment: "If you don't want the exception, catch the exception." did you really just tell me to use exceptions for flow control? x____x

Comment: I told you to use exceptions for *exception handling*, and what is a malformed date if not an exceptional case?

Comment: It's either a date or something else (an integer, etc.). It's perfectly valid in my program, I just need to know which it is.

Comment: ... how come you don't already know the type?  Short of NLP, I can't think of too many ways that "One of N possible Types, but not *sure* which" would be valid in *my* program.  In any case, `except ValueError: pass`, but I weep.

Comment: I just *don't*, because that's how my program is working... it's getting a little off-topic, sorry. I weep too. :(

Comment: @anonymous downvoter: I'm sorry you disagree with my answer;  This is really boils down to "No, there is no python equivalent to c#'s `DateTime.TryParse()` because TryParse *is not pythonic*".  All parsers in python raise `ValueError` when they encounter input they cannot parse.

Comment: `TryParse` with an `if/else` is from the behaviour standpoint no different from a `try/catch` but it's much cleaner than handling an exception that isn't one. There is no such thing as _idiomatic pythonic_ or maybe not implementing member accessibility in the language itself and using the `_` underscore as a workaround is? LOL

Answer (score 14):

We want to `try...catch` multiple datetime formats `fmt1,fmt2,...,fmtn` and suppress/handle the exceptions (from `strptime`) for all those that mismatch (and in particular, avoid needing a yukky n-deep indented ladder of `try..catch` clauses). I found two elegant ways, the second is best in general. (This is big problem on real-world data where multiple, mismatched, incomplete, inconsistent and multilanguage/region date formats are often mixed freely in one dataset.)

**1) Individually try applying each format and handle each individual `strptime()` fail as a return-value of `None`, so you can chain fn calls...**

To start off, adapting from @OrWeis' answer for compactness:

```
def try_strptime_single_format(s, fmt):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, fmt)
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Now you can invoke as `try_strptime(s, fmt1) or try_strptime(s, fmt2) or try_strptime(s, fmt3) ...` But we can improve that to:

**2) Apply multiple possible formats (either pass in as an argument or use sensible defaults), iterate over those, catch and handle any errors internally:**

Cleaner, simpler and more OO-friendly is to generalize this to make the `formats` parameter either a single string or a list, then iterate over that... so your invocation reduces to `try_strptime(s, [fmt1, fmt2, fmt3, ...])`

```
def try_strptime(s, fmts=['%d-%b-%y','%m/%d/%Y']):
    for fmt in fmts:
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(s, fmt)
        except:
            continue

    return None # or reraise the ValueError if no format matched, if you prefer
```

(As a sidebar, note that `...finally` is not the droid we want, since it would execute after each loop pass i.e. on each candidate format, not once at the end of the loop.)

I find implementation 2) is cleaner and better. In particular the function/method can store a list of default formats, which makes it more failsafe and less exception-happy on real-world data. (We could even infer which default formats to apply based on other columns, e.g. first try German date formats on German data, Arabic on Arabic, weblog datetime formats on weblog data etc.)

Comment: the exception should be ValueError for completeness `except ValueError:

Answer (score 5):

No, what you're asking for is not idiomatic Python, and so there generally won't be functions that discard errors like that in the standard library.  The relevant standard library modules are documented here:

http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

http://docs.python.org/library/time.html

The parsing functions all raise exceptions on invalid input.

However, as the other answers have stated, it wouldn't be terribly difficult to construct one for your application (your question was phrased "in Python" rather than "in the Python standard library" so it's not clear if assistance writing such a function "in Python" is answering the question or not).

Comment: What's the best way to enumerate the exceptions that might be thrown?

Comment: I doubt there is one. `except Exception:` if you want to catch 'em all (almost, see also `BaseException`).

Comment: @qneill You mean catch several exceptions in one line to treat them in the same way?
`except ValueError, KeyboardError:` (py3); `except (ValueError, KeyboardError):` (py2)

Answer (score 5):

Here's an equivalent function implementation

```
import datetime

def try_strptime(s, format):
    """
    @param s the string to parse
    @param format the format to attempt parsing of the given string
    @return the parsed datetime or None on failure to parse 
    @see datetime.datetime.strptime
    """
    try:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, format)
    except ValueError:
        date = None
    return date
```

Comment: Beautiful! This is actually the nicest way to implement, if we need to try multiple formats and don't want to build a clunky n-deep indented `try..except` ladder. You probably want to point out the elegance of this: you can chain it `try_strptime(s, fmt1) or try_strptime(s, fmt2) or try_strptime(s, fmt3) ...`. You could even generalize this to make `formats` parameter either a single string or a list, and iterate over them... `try_strptime(s, [fmt1, fmt2, fmt3, ...])`

Comment: I generalized your answer to [mine below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615533/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-cs-datetime-tryparse/47876446#47876446), I think it's even nicer...

Answer (score 3):

Brute force is also an option:

```py
def TryParse(datestring, offset):
    nu = datetime.datetime.now()
    retval = nu
    formats = ["%d-%m-%Y","%Y-%m-%d","%d-%m-%y","%y-%m-%d"]  

    if datestring == None:
        retval = datetime.datetime(nu.year,nu.month,nu.day,0,0,0) - datetime.timedelta(offset,0,0,0,0,0,0)
    elif datestring == '':
        retval = datetime.datetime(nu.year,nu.month,nu.day,0,0,0) - datetime.timedelta(offset,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
    else:
        succes = False
        for aformat in formats:
            try:
                retval = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring,aformat)
                succes = True
                break
            except:
                pass
        if not succes:
            retval = datetime.datetime(nu.year,nu.month,nu.day,0,0,0) - datetime.timedelta(offset,0,0,0,0,0,0) 
    return retval
```

Comment: You can easily refactor the subtracting `datetime.timedelta(offset,0,0,0,0,0,0)` to the bottom of the ladder. In fact this is more amenable to a helper function, `return retval` takes one line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `time.strptime` to parse dates from strings.

Documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime

Examples from: http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html

```
#----------------------------- 
# Parsing Dates and Times from Strings

time.strptime("Tue Jun 16 20:18:03 1981")
# (1981, 6, 16, 20, 18, 3, 1, 167, -1)

time.strptime("16/6/1981", "%d/%m/%Y")
# (1981, 6, 16, 0, 0, 0, 1, 167, -1)
# strptime() can use any of the formatting codes from time.strftime()

# The easiest way to convert this to a datetime seems to be; 
now = datetime.datetime(*time.strptime("16/6/1981", "%d/%m/%Y")[0:5])
# the '*' operator unpacks the tuple, producing the argument list.
```

Comment: I'd hate to give a -1 (sorry...), but there's a reason I said the equivalent of **`TryParse`** and not `Parse`...

Comment: Would "No, there's no equivalent" be a more helpful answer?

Answer (score 0):

I agree tryparse is very useful function on c#. Unfortunately no equivalent direct function of that in python (may be i am not aware). I believe you want to check a string is whether date or not without worrying about date format. My recommendation is go for `pandas` `to_datetime` function:

```
def is_valid_date(str_to_validate: str) -> bool:
    try:
        if pd.to_datetime(str_to_validate):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score -2):

How about strptime?

http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime

It will throw a ValueError if it is unable to parse the string based on the format that is provided.

---

Edit:

Since the question was edited to include the bit about exceptions after I answered it. I wanted to add a note about that.

As was pointed out in other answers, if you don't want your program to raise an exception, you can simply catch it and handle it:

```
try:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
except ValueError:
    date = None
```

That's a Pythonic way to do what you want.

Comment: I'd hate to give a -1 (sorry...), but there's a reason I said the equivalent of **`TryParse`** and not `Parse`...